# Error Play Store app is either not installed or not the official version on Google Play Asset Delivery

Tags: android, kotlin, google-play, google-play-services

I'm following [this document](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/asset-delivery) to setup Play Asset Delivery which download few **on-demand packages** in my app.
It works very well on all my devices when I upload into google play internal testing/production channel.

```
assetPackManager.registerListener(downloadListener)                                    

assetPackManager.fetch(listOf(packageName)).addOnCompleteListener{ res ->
 Timber.i("Download $packageName ${res.isSuccessful}")
}
```

But I got many error reports from firebase crashlytics which I don't know how to resolve:

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.Exception com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.b: -11: 
 Asset Pack Download Error(-11): The Play Store app is either not installed or not the 
   official version. 
(https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/assetpacks/model/AssetPackErrorCode.html#PLAY_STORE_NOT_FOUND) at 
   com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.e0.l(Unknown Source:21) at 
   com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.e0.f(Unknown Source:4) at 
   com.google.android.play.core.assetpacks.o4.g(Unknown Source:19) at 
   com.bookbot.i.s(Unknown Source:231) at com.bookbot.i.C(Unknown Source:24) at 
   com.bookbot.i.f(Unknown Source:0) at com.bookbot.h.run(Unknown Source:6) at 
   android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:883) at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100) at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214) at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7397) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:492) at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:935)
```

[This document](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/play/core/assetpacks/model/AssetPackErrorCode.html#PLAY_STORE_NOT_FOUND) say `The Play Store app is either not installed or not the official version`, but I don't really understand it. My app is only published into google play by using app bundle, I don't publish into anywhere else, so I wonder why it says playstore not official?

Here are some affected devices:

```
AT&T Fusion Z (android 10)
Galaxy S9  (android 10)
vsmart (android 11)
```

Is there any way to resolve this issue? Or at least can check if device is not supported by Play Asset Delivery?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the error message is telling you exactly what's wrong -- those specific devices either had their Play Store app removed or disabled. Or they could be rooted, and the Play Store app was modified. Or those devices could be set up without Google Services at all, and use alternate app stores.

It's easy enough to test for, though. Just use `GoogleApiAvailability`:

```
val result = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().isGooglePlayServicesAvailable(activityContext)
```

and from there you can either implement your own logic, or have Google display their error dialog:

```
val dialog = GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(activityContext, result, 123)
dialog?.show()
```

You can also set up `onActivityResult()` to check the response from the error dialog

Comment: Thank you. I knew about checking google play service available, but is it the same for this google play problem like root or not available?

Comment: yes, it'll tell you if Play Services are usable or not